# How do I find out the Git commands used at the start of the job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to debug some Git related stuff, but really want to know all the Git commands the runner is calling at the start of a job. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your own runners, you can set `pre_clone_script` to `set -x`. This might output all the commands in verbose mode. See also: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section.

What gitlab does also depends on what stage the job is running. Is it at the beginning, in the middle, or towards the end? I'm using the docker runner which typically does:

- Download the docker image used for the build
- Login into the docker image
- Load the cache from a previous job
- Delete all the changes from the previous job, similiar to `git clean -qfdx`
- checkout the hash you want to build, similar to `git checkout 234nsdfgow45sdfkj`
- download artifacts from all previous build jobs, if there are any
- start whatever is defined in the `script:` section of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Look at the output of your job from the beginning. You are better off to describe what your actual problem is rather than "debug" all the git commands gitlab does for you.